# filtering names in jquery input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that selects all the text fields with "record_" in them.

```
$('input[name^="record_"]').map(function() { total += $(this).val() * 1; });
```

But the fields with the name "record_1, record_2 and record_3" need to be * 8 not * 1.

How can i filter the search so that it only finds records that have numbers after 3?
I tried an IF function but the way ive done the above code means that "record_15" will be * 8 and not * 1 as it should be .
I know this should be simple but i cant get my head around it.

Comment: Not the answer to your problem, just a tip: You should use `each` instead of `map`.  `map` is for converting a jQuery object to an array, while `each` will just go through the DOM elements and run the provided function on them.

Comment: cheers the tip, ill try and do that in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
$('input[name^="record_"]').each(function() {
    total += this.value * (parseInt(this.name.substr(7),10)<4 ? 8 : 1);
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/WKb7n/1/

It also avoids creating unnecessary variables or lookups inside the loop, which should make it more efficient.

Comment: (1) `each` instead of `map` is more appropriate; (2) `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()` performs better and is more readable; (3) Pass in the radix `10` into `parseInt`; (4) `this.name` instead of `$(this).attr('name')` - same reason as (2)

Comment: @Šime: You are right, on every count. I'll update my code, and upvote your answer too.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$('input[name^="record_"]').map(function() { 
    var name = this.name;
    var number = name.replace('record_', '')
    if (number > 3){
         total += $(this).val() * 1; 
    }else{
         total += $(this).val() * 8; 
    }
    console.log(number);


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( 'input[name^="record_"]' ).each(function () {
    var n = +this.name.split( '_' )[1];
    total += this.value * ( n > 3 ? 1 : 8 );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/QAMcA/1/

Comment: Just curious though -- why create a local variable inside the 'loop' function? Just for readability? (not that that isn't a perfectly valid reason)

Comment: @Jens Yes, for readability. It often happens that I want to put a comment at the end of local variables to explain those values. Also note that local variables are super-cheap and they can be used in abundance to make the code more readable.

Comment: Local variables are cheap, but I still tend to  avoid them in loops and recursive functions, but that does make the code less readable and in a lot of situations the gain is negligible

Comment: @Jens Note that "declaring variables inside loops" does not exist in JavaScript. JavaScript does not have block scope, and all local variables are created beforehand (= during the initialization of the execution context, **before** any statements are evaluated). Hence, having `var x = ...;` inside a loop is equivalent to having a regular assignment `x = ...;` inside that loop. With that being said, variable statements inside loops is missleading, since those variables are **not** repeatedly declared on every iteration.

Comment: @Jens But even if you were to have variable declarations inside a loop, there wouldn't be any performance cost because of that. [See here](http://jsperf.com/declaring-local-variables-inside-iteration-statements)

Comment: @Jens As for having local variables inside recursive functions, as I said, the cost of declaring a local variable is neglectable ([see here](http://jsperf.com/declaring-local-variables-inside-recursive-functions)).